# control flow for loops that identify chapters in a book

Tags: python, loops, control-flow

I am trying to write a function that loops through a .txt file of a books and identifies chapters.  I am using the appearance of more than one \n in a row followed by one line of non \n text to signify a new chapter.   How would you guys structure the loops to do this?  I personally am using python, but you should feel free to keep your answers as abstract as possible.

Comment: so have you actually tried anything? what have you tried? why didnt it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chapters = filter(None,map(str.strip,text.split("\n\n")))
```

you could also do it with re using Stevens answer from the comments

Comment: Sometimes regular expressions are good: `chapters = re.split('\n{2,}', text)`

Comment: I used re at first ... but realized I would not get much benefit as you would still need to filter it (or at least check first and last chapters for emptyness)

Comment: Why is a check for emptiness needed?

Comment: `\n\nChapter1\n\nChapter2\n\n` would likely be a valid file ... but the re.split puts empties in first and last

Comment: I was trying and failing to do it with for loops and while loop.  This is much more straight forward.  You guys are AWESOME.

Comment: No `lambda` needed on the `filter`, just pass `None` as the function.

Comment: I'd replace `map(lambda x: x.strip(), ...)` with `[x.strip() for x in ...]`

Comment: @IsmailBadawi that is also a reasonable solution ... but just saying what you would do instead without a why is not very constructive (I got rid of both lambdas btw)